# script file command not found

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, scripts, sh

I have a simple script file ***first.sh*** as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello";
a = "test";
echo "$a"
```

when I execute it, it occurs an error as written below:

**./first.sh: line 3: a: command not found**

Answer (score 3):

Remove spaces in `a = "test";` to be `a="test";`